# Scrapy spider not scraping the data correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape the data about the circulrs from my college's website using scrapy for a project but my spider is not scraping the data properly. There are a lot of blank elements and also I am unable to scrape the 'href' attributes of the circulars for some reason. I am assuming that my CSS selectors are wrong but I am unable to figure out what am I doing wrong exactly. I copied my CSS selectors using the 'Selector Gadget' Chrome extension. I ams till learning scrapy so it would be great if you could explain what I was doing wrong.

The Website I am scraping data from is : https://www.imsnsit.org/imsnsit/notifications.php

My code is :

```
import scrapy
from ..items import CircularItem

class CircularSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "circular"
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.imsnsit.org/imsnsit/notifications.php"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = CircularItem()
        all = response.css('tr~ tr+ tr font')
        for x in all:
            cirName = x.css('a font::text').extract()
            cirLink = x.css('.list-data-focus a').attrib['href'].extract()
            date = x.css('tr~ tr+ tr td::text').extract()
            items["Name"] = cirName
            items["href"] = cirLink
            items["Date"] = date
            yield items
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your parse callback function. I changed CSS selectors into xpath. Also, try to learn [xpath selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-xpaths) they are very powerful and easy to use.
Generally, It is bad idea to copy CSS or xpath using automatic selectors, because in some cases they might give you incorrect results or just one element without general path.

First of all I select all `tr`. If you look carefully, some of `tr` are just blank used for separator. You can filter them by trying to select `date`, if it is `None` you can just skip the row. And finally you can just select `cirName` and `cirLink`.

Also, markup of the given website is not good and It is really hard to write proper selectors, elements don't have many attributes, like `class` or `id`. That's the solution I came up with, I know it is not perfect.

```
def parse(self, response):
    items = CircularItem()
    all = response.xpath('//tr') # select all table items
    for x in all:
        date = x.xpath('.//td/font[@size="3"]/text()').get() # filter them by date
        if not date:
            continue
        cirName = x.xpath('.//a/font/text()').get()
        cirLink = x.xpath('.//a[@title="NOTICES / CIRCULARS"]/@href').get()
        items["Name"] = cirName
        items["href"] = cirLink
        items["Date"] = date
        yield items
```